# Output of php is limited

Tags: php, sockets

I have a problem here, maybe someone has already gone through this before.

A system controller is serving php downloads, it reads information from files and sends the client as a download. The system works perfectly. The problem is that speed is always low, always less than the 300kb/se times less than 100kb / s for the user.

The server has a 100mbps link 6mbps free and the customer has, then it should be downloaded at 600kb / s. Something is holding the output of php. I've tried searching on the buffers of apache but found nothing on this issue.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Not a programming question sounds more like serverfault to me...

Comment: You can't judge the download speed by just the speeds on either end. It is affected by the slowest router in the path. Also, with ISPs, you may get high speed ADSL, but their uplink may be clogged with too many users. Anyway, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 6):

PHP really isn't built for processing large files. It has to read that entire file into memory and then output it. It sounds like you're sending a reasonable amount of traffic through PHP, if 100kb/s - 300kb/s per user is too slow, via something like `readfile()` which is a bad idea. Instead, I suggest taking a look at `mod_xsendfile` (if you're using Apache) or it's equivalent for your web server of choice (e.g. I prefer nginx, and would use `XSendFile` for this).

In PHP then, you can just do this: `header('X-Sendfile: ' . $file);`. The server intercepts the header, and sends that file. It allows you the benefits of what you're doing with PHP, and the speed of the web server directly reading the file.

Comment: Nor, because php has to regulate how many and which bytes are sent to the client, because while it sends to the client he is downloading from another server.

The output of php is not slow, so he could save those 600mb disk in very little time. The data are transmitted tothe client that being barred .

This would only mod_sendfile if the file has been downloaded to disk. And if you do not know how to protect the file or if this is just a redirect. Plus, would not handle the mime type and file name that go to the client, since apache ignores everything else.